# PHP DOMDocument parentNode->replaceChild causing foreach to skip next item

Tags: php, iframe, foreach, html-parser

I am parsing html in the `$content` variable with the DOMDocument to replace all iframes with images.  The foreach is only replacing the ODD iframes.  I have removed all the code in the foreach and found the piece of code causing this is: '$iframe->parentNode->replaceChild($link, $iframe);'

Why would the foreach be skipping all of the odd iframes?

The code:

```
        $count = 1;
        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        $dom->loadHTML($content);
        $iframes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('iframe');
        foreach ($iframes as $iframe) {

            $src = $iframe->getAttribute('src');
            $width = $iframe->getAttribute('width');
            $height = $iframe->getAttribute('height');

            $link = $dom->createElement('img');
            $link->setAttribute('class', 'iframe-'.self::return_video_type($iframe->getAttribute('src')).' iframe-'.$count.' iframe-ondemand-placeholderImg');
            $link->setAttribute('src', $placeholder_image);
            $link->setAttribute('height', $height);
            $link->setAttribute('width', $width);
            $link->setAttribute('data-iframe-src', $src);

            $iframe->parentNode->replaceChild($link, $iframe);

            echo "here:".$count;
            $count++;
        }

        $content = $dom->saveHTML();

        return $content;
```

This is the problem line of code

```
        $iframe->parentNode->replaceChild($link, $iframe);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A [DOMNodeList](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php), such as that returned from [`getElementsByTagName`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php), is ["live"](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-DOM-Level-3-Core-20030226/DOM3-Core.html#core-td-live):

> that is, changes to the underlying document structure are reflected in all relevant NodeList... objects

So when you remove the element (in this case by replacing it with another one) it no longer exists in the node list, and the next one in line takes its position in the index. Then when `foreach` hits the next iteration, and hence the next index, one will be effectively skipped.

Don't remove elements from the DOM via `foreach` like this.

---

An approach that works instead would be to use a `while` loop to iterate and replace until your `$iframes` node list is empty.

#### Example:

```
while ($iframes->length) {
    $iframe = $iframes->item(0);

    $src = $iframe->getAttribute('src');
    $width = $iframe->getAttribute('width');
    $height = $iframe->getAttribute('height');

    $link = $dom->createElement('img');
    $link->setAttribute('class', 'iframe-'.self::return_video_type($iframe->getAttribute('src')).' iframe-'.$count.' iframe-ondemand-placeholderImg');
    $link->setAttribute('src', $placeholder_image);
    $link->setAttribute('height', $height);
    $link->setAttribute('width', $width);
    $link->setAttribute('data-iframe-src', $src);

    $iframe->parentNode->replaceChild($link, $iframe);

    echo "here:".$count;
    $count++;
}
```

Comment: but when length is equal to 1 .Then while loop become infinite.So what to do in this case

Comment: If an element within the DomNodeList is not replaced then this will loop forever.

Answer (score 6):

Faced this issue today, and guide by the answer, i make a simple code solution for you guys

```
$iframes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('iframe');
for ($i=0; $i< $iframes->length; $i++) {
    $iframe = $iframes->item($i);
    if("condition to replace"){
        // do some replace thing
        $i--;
    }
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: $i-- isn't needed, and is messing up the for loop.

Comment: @KariKääriäinen `$iframes` is reference value, if you replace one of `iframe` element, indexing of `$iframes` change. But `$i` is not, then you need minus `$i` to avoiding out-of-index errors and not skipping some elements.

Answer (score 0):

If was looking for a way to skip some of the elements, and replace the others. When you alter the array it indeed skips the iteration. In this example you can see the code continues to the next iteration if the code doen't have een attribute src that starts with foo/bar.

```
$elems = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
$amountElems = $elems->length;
for ($i=($amountElems-1); $i >= 0; $i--) {       
    $elem = $elems->item($i);
    if (!str_starts_with($elem->getAttribute('src'), '/foo/bar/')) continue;
    // TLDR some code to alter or create a new elem 
    $elem->parentNode->removeChild($elem);
}
```